Convergent subsequences in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$
This is a particular fact that I ended up proving in the process of attempting one of my recent homeworks, but I don't think I've seen this particular fact online even though it feels like a fairly simple fact and I so I'm not entirely sure if I have made an error somewhere or if I have simply stated some obvious well known fact.

Let $\{u_k\}_{k \in \mathbb N} \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)^\mathbb N$ be such that for any fixed compact set $C$, we have that:
$$\int_C|u_k|^2 dx = \|u_k\|_{L^2(C)}^2 < K(C)$$
In other words, it is uniformly bounded irrespective of $k$ and only dependent on $C$. Then there exists a subsequence of $u_k$ such that for any compactly supported $\varphi \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \varphi u_k \, dx \to \int_{\mathbb R^n} \varphi u \,dx$$
For some $u$ measurable, in other words, $u_k \to u$ weakly in some sense.

The proof idea is pretty simple, knowing that bounded $L^2$ sequences admit a weakly convergent subsequence (Banach-Alaoglu), we may extract a convergent subsequence $\{u_{k_1(n)}\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in the weak $L^2$ topology on the ball $B_1$ of radius $1$ at the origin. Repeating this process, we extract a sub-subsequence $\{u_{k_2(n)}\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ convergent on $B_2$. Iteratively, we extract a subsequence of $\{u_{k_m(n)}\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$, call it $\{u_{k_{m+1}(n)}\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$, so that it is convergent in $L^2$ weakly on $B_{m+1}$. Taking the diagonal sequence now, $\{u_{k_n(n)}\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is weakly convergent on every ball of finite radius and thus weakly convergent (the integral against a compactly supported $\varphi$ would converge since $u_k$ is strongly convergent on $\varphi$'s support).
In particular, I'd be very grateful if someone could point out if my proof has an error in it, specifically I'm a bit concerned about whether the limits remain consistent each time a extract a subsequence. Or if someone could point me to a reference of this fact.

The $L^2$ spaces are infinite-dimensional normed spaces, hence there always exist bounded sequences which don't admit norm-convergent subsequences, otherwise the closed balls would be compact. For Hilbert spaces it's even easier to see since you can just look at any orthonormal basis and see that they have to weakly converge to $0$, so if they could converge in norm it would be to $0$, but all the elements are of norm $1$. I have a feeling you'll need to take advantage of your condition a bit more to get the desired result.

Good point, I can't believe I overlooked this although this is an easy fix. I'll add an edit, thanks!

I was going to say that Banach-Alaoglu was for weak-star topologies, but I suppose that for reflexive spaces weak and weak-star are one and the same, huh. Anyway, this seems correct now, and your weak limit is indeed preserved through taking subsequences, so that the "diagonal" weak limit is definable everywhere and unique on each ball (by uniqueness of the weak limit on $L^2$ of each ball).

I didn't think you can convince that the "weak limit" is actually in $L^2(R^n)$ as you claim. This will only hold locally

Right @PhoemueX, I'll just say measurable, thanks!

@BrunoB, yea at some point all these compactness/convergence conditions for functions have blended together into one blur for me.
